# New window with embedded VLCJ video

Tags: java, video, canvas, vlcj

I have a jpanel, inside a canvas to play a embedded video on it, using VLCJ.

Well, when a play the video, it plays correctly in the canvas, BUT in a new window too, and i dont want a new window.

I get this error BUT it plays perfectly (except i dont want a new windown, just the canvas)

`[0bf590e8] main vout display error: Failed to set on top`

And this is my part of my code

```
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvasVideo);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

    mediaPlayer.playMedia("C:\\juego.mp4");
```

Any help Please?

Comment: vlc will open up a native window if it does not have a valid window handle when the video is played. So somehow your Canvas may have become invalid. Did you try any of the test players provided with vlcj to compare results?

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to use EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent. For example

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test vlcj toolkit");
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
frame.setSize(1050, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("C:\\juego.mp4");
```

Comment: It's convenient to use EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent, but not necessary.